# include_once(../../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, apache, xampp, wamp

My Files Path like >>

```
/config.php
/fold_1/fold_2/functions.php
/fold_1/myfile.php
```

functions.php contain >>

```
include_once("../../config.php");
function addition($x,$y){return($x+$y);}
function substraction($x,$y){return($x-$y);}
```

myfile.php contain >>

```
include_once("fold_2/functions.php");
call addition(2,3);
```

but it gives warning like >>

```
include_once(../../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or 
directory
```

i know the reason is like when i include `function.php` in `myfile.php` it will replace all code of `function.php` to `myfile.php` and then run the code of `function.php` so it can't able to find the `config.php` file at `../../config.php`

but i wan't to know is there any solution **(solution means changing some variables value in php.ini or like that)** to overcome this problem so it can run the code of `functions.php` first and after it will mapped to the `myfile.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using like this:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/path/to/config.php';
```

sometimes PHP and the server prefer full absolute paths rather than `../../` - I usually fix using `$_SERVER`

Comment: yah you are right that's really works for me, Thanks you Sir. 
and did you really have two thumbs? Cool
like in our country  one actor "hrithik roshan" also have.

Comment: @Stranger no problem, glad I could help :)